# Telegram bot webhook doesn't receive new chat member username

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm using a Telegram bot webhook to receive an [Update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) object when a new user joins a group the bot is in. I was expecting to receive more information about the user, but all I get is:

```
"new_chat_members": [
    {
        "id": xxxxxxxxx,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "xxxxx"
    }
]
```

I understand I could use the [getFullUser](https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser) API endpoint, but I'd rather not make an additional request. Is there a way to include the username to the data received there?

Comment: I have the same problem, have u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `bot.send_message(cid, str(m))` you will get all information of the message:

```js
{
    'left_chat_member': None,
    'migrate_from_chat_id': None,
    'content_type': 'new_chat_members',
    'date': '1533552871',
    'voice': None,
    'migrate_to_chat_id': None,
    'group_chat_created': None,
    'location': None,
    'sticker': None,
    'new_chat_photo': None,
    'forward_from': None,
    'channel_chat_created': None,
    'video': None,
    'pinned_message': None,
    'supergroup_chat_created': None,
    'chat': {
        'id': idGroup,
        'title': 'groupTitle',
        'first_name': None,
        'last_name': None,
        'username': None,
        'all_members_are_administrators': None,
        'type': 'supergroup'
    },
    'audio': None,
    'reply_to_message': None,
    'caption': None,
    'contact': None,
    'document': None,
    'entities': None,
    'message_id': '688',
    'photo': None,
    'new_chat_title': None,
    'successful_payment': None,
    'forward_from_chat': None,
    'venue': None,
    'forward_date': None,
    'invoice': None,
    'text': None,
    'edit_date': None,
    'video_note': None,
    'from_user': {
        'username': 'username',
        'last_name': None,
        'first_name': 'userFirstName',
        'id': id,
        'language_code': 'es'
    },
    'delete_chat_photo': None,
    'new_chat_members': [{
        'id': id,
        'is_bot': True,
        'first_name': 'UserName',
        'username': 'newUserName'
    }],
    'new_chat_member': {
        'username': 'username',
        'last_name': None,
        'first_name': 'firstNameUser',
        'id': idUser,
        'language_code': None
    }
}
```

My code is in `python3`. You can try it this and add more information about the new user:

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['new_chat_members'])
    def command_hi(m):
        cid = m.chat.id
        cname = m.chat.title
        idUser = message.from_user.id

        welcome = ""
        if (m.new_chat_member.username is None):
            nun = m.new_chat_member.first_name
            if (m.new_chat_member.last_name is not None):
                nun += " "
                nun += m.new_chat_member.last_name
            else:
                welcome= "Welcome to the group"
                welcome += str(cname)
                welcome += " "
        else:
            nun = m.new_chat_member.username
            welcome= "Welcome to the group  "
            welcome+= str(cname)
            welcome+= " @"

        bot.send_message(cid, str(welcome) + str(nun))
```